# How to parse additional arguments based on presence of another argument in getopt in c++

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, getopt

I need a way to say if the user inputs `-f <optarg>` I need `-n <optarg>` and `-o <optarg>` but if the user does not specify `-f`, `-n -o` are not necessary.I have to do such similar condition based  extra arguements parsing for a number of cases.Is it possible using getopt? Can anyone help me doing this?

I don't want to check every variable after parsing. I was hoping if there is any regular expression I can use in the getopt string that would get my job done.

Comment: parse everything and then check at the end if you got everything you need?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in your `getopt` loop, you set different variables based on the specified flags.  After the loop completes, you could easily check the states of these variables.  For example:

```
const char* someVariable = NULL;
const char* someOtherVariable = NULL;

while ((opt = getopt(argc, arv, "f:n:")) != -1)
{
    switch (opt)
    {
        case 'f':
            someVariable = optarg;
            break;
        case 'n':
            someOtherVariable = optarg;
            break;
    }
}

if (someVariable != NULL)
{
    if (someOtherVariable == NULL)
    {
        fputs("-f specified without -n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah this is how I am doing right now but I felt it is a crude way to do it and I was wondering if there is any way to specify this in the getopt expression. Since I have to do this for a number of cases, code becomes cluttered with if loops.

Comment: @VivekVK This is the way you have to do it, with `getopt` or with anything else.  Otherwise how would you handle `-f ARG -n ARG -o ARG` *and* `-o ARG -n ARG -f ARG`?  You can check that all of the options have been supplied only *after* you've finished processing all of the options.